# Delete Folders from CSV List

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that lists 59 folder paths that I wish to delete.
This is the code I am using-

```
$Folders = Import-Csv -Path "path to csv file"

foreach ($folder in $Folders){
if (Test-Path $folder) {
 
    Write-Host "Folder Exists"
    Remove-Item $folder -Recurse -Force
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Folder Doesn't Exists"
}

}
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
folders
E:\path1
E:\path2
E:\path3
```

However the script does not work and it returns "Folder Doesnt Exist", though they do exist.
What am I missing?

Comment: You should debug your script. As a minimum, add to your logs $folder name, e.g. Write-Host "Folder $folder Doesn't Exists"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Folders` contains rows from the original file. So each `$folder` is a row from the original file, not the column value, i.e. file name.

You access columns from the rows by using the header name, "folders" in your case:

```
$Folders = Import-Csv -Path "path to csv file"

foreach ($folder in $Folders) {
   if (Test-Path $folder.folders) {
 
       Write-Host "Folder Exists"
       Remove-Item $folder.folders -Recurse -Force
   }
   else
   {
       Write-Host "Folder Doesn't Exists"
   }
}
```

In short: Use `$folder.folders` to access the actual value.

You can see the difference like so:

```
 PS> Import-CSV .\foo.csv | % { Write-host $_ }
 @{folders=E:\path1}
 @{folders=E:\path2}
 @{folders=E:\path3}

 PS> Import-CSV .\foo.csv | % { Write-host $_.folders }
 E:\path1
 E:\path2
 E:\path3
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing [Christian.K's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71369167/7571258), you may use the following alternative ways:

Use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with parameter `-ExpandProperty` (alias `-Expand`) to extract the `Folders` column directly at the source:

```
$Folders = Import-Csv -Path "path to csv file" | Select-Object -Expand Folders
```

Use [member enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#member-enumeration) to create an array of strings from the `Folders` property :

```
foreach ($folder in $Folders.Folders) { 
    ...
}
```